# check a checkbox based on the contents of an observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I got struck with the checkbox bind using knockout js. I use two observable arrays. First observable array is used to display all the student details value with the checkbox in the view. In the 2nd observable array I obtain some values filtered that need to be checked(true) dynamically in the view where I have already displayed the checkbox with the whole value. My html code is,

```html
<div class="col-lg-10" style="white-space:pre">
    <div class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="foreach: $root.Studentdetails">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="
            checkedValue: $data,value:id(),
            checked: $root.associatedItemIds,
            click: $root.toggleAssociation
        " />
        <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the way i approach to gets the checkbox selecetd,

```
self.associatedItemIds=ko.obsearvablearray();   
self.associatedItemIds.push(response.CheckStudents);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @connexo: I need to get the checkbox dynamically selecetd for the values I hold in an observable array.

Answer (score 3):

Either you check your checkboxes by object reference (i.e, using `$data`). Then you will have an array of selected *students*.

Or you check your checkboxes by a value (like the student Id). Then you will have an array of *student Ids*.

In no case you need any `click` handlers or the `value` binding, knockout does everything on its own. Take some time to read [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) again.

Compare:

```js
function StudentList(students) {
  this.Studentdetails = ko.observableArray(students);
  this.associatedItems = ko.observableArray();
}

var students = [
  {Id: 1, Name: 'Student 1'},
  {Id: 2, Name: 'Student 2'},
  {Id: 3, Name: 'Student 3'},
  {Id: 4, Name: 'Student 4'}
];

var vm = new StudentList(students);
vm.associatedItems.push(students[2]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="foreach: $root.Studentdetails">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="
            checkedValue: $data,
            checked: $root.associatedItems,
        " />
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span><br>
    </div>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

and:

```js
function StudentList(students) {
  this.Studentdetails = ko.observableArray(students);
  this.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();
}

var students = [
  {Id: 1, Name: 'Student 1'},
  {Id: 2, Name: 'Student 2'},
  {Id: 3, Name: 'Student 3'},
  {Id: 4, Name: 'Student 4'}
];

var vm = new StudentList(students);
vm.associatedItemIds.push(students[2].Id);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="foreach: $root.Studentdetails">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="
            checkedValue: Id,
            checked: $root.associatedItemIds,
        " />
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span><br>
    </div>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: but i need to get the checkbox dynamically checked(selected) for the values I hold in an observable array. U have gave me an idea to get the values of the checkbox selected.

Comment: I have also shown you how dynamic selection based on an array works. Run the code snippets. Think about what the line `vm.associatedItems.push(students[2]);` in my first sample does and you will understand.

Comment: Your fiddle does not even run. Sorry, but I don't have the time to first fix your fiddle and then find the error in your code. Assume the people here have a life besides StackOverflow. They invest their spare time to help others, for free. It's your job to make it as easy for them as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'chl'+Id},value: Id, checked:$root.associatedItemIds">

  self.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();

  for (var key in self.ProductsList()) {
            self.associatedItemIds.push("" + self.ProductsList()[key].Id);
        }
```